# Selection sort - stable

Tags: c

I read that instead of swapping , we can insert to change selection sorting to a stable sort. I got the following implementation of the same online.

```
void selection ( int a[], int n ) {
    while ( --n > 0 ) {
        int i, max = n;

        for ( i = 0; i < n; i++ ) {
            if ( a[i] >= a[max] )
                max = i;
        }

        if ( max != n ) {
            int save = a[max];

            for ( i = max; i < n; i++ )
                a[i] = a[i + 1];

            a[n] = save;
        }
    }
}
```

I dont understand how this will be a stable sort for the following:
(1,0), (2,0), (5,0), (4,0), (5,1)

I think the above mentioned implementation will give 
(1,0), (2,0), (4,0), (5,1), (5,0)

I dont see this as a stable behaviour as i understands it. Am i correct. If so how can i implement a stable selection sort.

The following code when changed will give us a stable selection sort. Correct me if I am wrong.

```
    for ( i = 0; i < n; i++ ) {
        if ( a[i] >= a[max] )
        max = i;
    }
```

That line wont give us the desired result i think, In this case , it wont give a stable result for the data i gave for sorting. I think that the following code will do fine.

```
    for ( i = 0; i <= n; i++ ) {
        if ( a[i] >= a[max] )
        max = i;
    }
```

Correct me if I am wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The code you posted seems to be a stable sort.

In the selection loop, the *last* occurence of the maximum value will always be selected. This is because the condition says `a[i] >= a[max]` rather than `a[i] > a[max]`.

```
for ( i = 0; i < n; i++ ) {
    if ( a[i] >= a[max] )
    max = i;
}
```

Then the selected element is placed at the end (where a stable sort should put it). The order of the rest of the elements is unchanged because they are all moved rather than swapping. This guarantees that elements with an equal value will remain in the same order, i.e. a stable sort.

Comment: Thanks for the response.

        for ( i = 0; i < n; i++ ) {
        if ( a[i] >= a[max] )
        max = i;
    }

That line wont give us the desired result i think, In this case , it wont give a stable result for the data i gave for sorting. I think that the following code will do fine.

        for ( i = 0; i <= n; i++ ) {
        if ( a[i] >= a[max] )
        max = i;
    }

Correct me if I am wrong?

Thanks

Comment: @trialyogi: Yes, you're right. It should be `for ( i = 0; i <= n; i++ )` so that it looks at all the elements, and then the sort will be stable.